# Angular mat-select get the selected option data object

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material2

Under my **Angular 7** app , i'm using the mat-select component :

```
<mat-form-field  class="col-md-3" color="warn">
     <mat-select placeholder="Selectionner le code Edo"
                  id="codeEdo"
                  [(value)]="selectedCodeEdoValue"
                  ngDefaultControl
                  formControlName="codeEdo">
     <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="onEdoSelectionChanged(edo )"
                 *ngFor="let edo of shopsList"
                  [value]="edo.edoId">
                  {{edo.edoId}}
     </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

My options data are the following:

```
let shopsList= [
  {
    'edoId': '4010',
    'storeName': 'ABBEVILLE'
  }
  ,
  {
    'edoId': '3650',
    'storeName': 'AGEN'
  }
  ,
  {
    'edoId': '3298',
    'storeName': 'AIX ALLEES PROVENCALES'
  }
];
```

My purpose is to get the **selected object data** when an option is selected , and not just the value

for example when i select the *first option* , i wanna get this :

```
result = {
    'edoId': '4010',
    'storeName': 'ABBEVILLE'
}
```

And not only the value **'4010'**

As you can see i ve tried this : `(onSelectionChange)="onEdoSelectionChanged(edo )`

But this fires me always **two events** , for the old selected option and the new selected option ,

**How may i only get the new selection data ??**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your error is with this bit of code:

> [value]="edo.edoId"

Try changing it to

> [value]="edo"

This will return the full object, instead of just that specific field

Comment: that's right , but my problem is that this method "onSelectionChange" fires me always two responses events : the old option data , and the new one , and i want only the second new one

Comment: You should use 'selection change' instead of  'onSelectionChange'
(selectionChange)="method($event)">